# OpenSSL crypto ENGINE_get_first() returns NULL

Tags: openssl, cryptography

I'm working on an iOS project and have a situation wherein if I link certain frameworks and bundles, a call to `ENGINE_get_first()` returns `NULL`. If I remove the references to the frameworks and bundles, I get a proper list of engines. Unfortunately, I need those frameworks!

I've tried all manner of `OPENSSL_config()`, `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()`, `ENGINE_load_builtin_engines()`, `ENGINE_register_all_complete()` and so on, but I always get a `NULL` return with these frameworks linked.

What could be causing these functions to fail when the additional frameworks and bundles are linked?

Comment: It sounds like someone ls is calling [`OPENSSL_config`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/OPENSSL_config.html) and mucking with your call to it, or changing your state in unexpected ways. Perhaps you can call `OPENSSL_config` once you enter your `main` function to get back into an expected state. Dynamic loading of engines seems like it should be a problem on iOS. Its not clear to me why it does not fail all the time.

Comment: @jww I'm in the process of a solution here. It looks like somehow by bringing in the additional frameworks a separate `libcrypto` was getting linked in. I assumed it was from `/usr/lib`, but I don't think that's possible because those `.dylib` files only support i386 and x86_64 architectures (not `arm64`). But perhaps the frameworks themselves contained dynamically linked libraries which were chosen over and above the version I had headers for. By tweaking my project settings and forcing a link to the archive I wanted the problem seems to be resolved. Twelve hours of debugging later!

Comment: @jww Oh, and just for chiming in with some helpful advice, if you want to submit an answer saying something along the lines of "I bet it's a linker error. Sounds like maybe multiple versions of OpenSSL are getting linked into your project or your headers aren't matched to the libraries" then I'll happily mark your answer as correct!

Comment: Thanks, but I think you can probably supply the best answer for future visitors. I also think you are spot-on with your analysis. `OPENSSL_config` is automatically called, and other libraries can inadvertently invoke it and contend with your expected configuration. I was contemplating a nearly-empty object file with one constructor method that called `OPENSSL_config`, but I think your solution of framework ordering is cleaner.